# Who loads bridge.ko modules when Linux system starts?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, bridge

When my CentOS Linux system starts, `bridge.ko` and `ebtable_broute` are loaded, I'd like to know which module is loading these modules.

```
[root]# lsmod | grep bridge
bridge                266240  0
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp

[root]# lsmod | grep ebtable_brout
ebtable_broute         16384  1
bridge                200704  1 ebtable_broute
ebtables               36864  3 ebtable_nat,ebtable_filter,ebtable_broute
```

Comment: ` [root]# lsmod | grep bridge bridge 266240 0 stp 16384 1 bridge llc 16384 2 bridge,stp`